# URL AMIGABLES PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hola necesito una ayuda para quitar el id y poner el titulo en vez del id pero la consulta que se haga x id, con id si me funciona la url amigable noticias/123 pero con el texto no logro o como oculto.

Link: noticias/detalle_noticia.php?detalle_noticia=123
Asi queria: seria noticias/hola-titulo-noticia

AHI USO UNA FUNCION PARA QUITAR CARACTERES ESPECIALES

```
<a href="../noticias/<?php echo urls_amigables($titulo); ?>">
```

.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^noticias/([^/\.]+)/?$ noticias/detalle_noticia.php?detalle_noticia=$1 [L]  
Options -Indexes
```

Pero como hago para hacer la consulta id envez de con texto porque tiene caracteres especiales.

Comment: Hola, ¿aún necesitas ayuda?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que no quiero mostrar el id en url solo mostrar el titulo y que la consulta se haga con id hay alguna forma